# Azure Managed Instance - Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, managed

I have setup an Azure VM that is linked to my Managed SQL, but I need to install SSMS and ODBC drivers but the machine tells me nothing can be installed.

Also, I did the install from this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connect-vm-instance-configure) and it was meant to do the SSMS install as part of the process

Do these need to be done via PowerShell scripts?  And if so, does anyone have one spare for this or another idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done directly, install from Browser using link [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) and [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and can also be done with PowerShell Script

PowerShell Script for Downlod SSMS

```
#Set file and folder path for SSMS installer .exe
    $folderpath="c:\windows\temp"
    $filepath="$folderpath\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe"
     
    #If SSMS not present, download
    if (!(Test-Path $filepath)){
    write-host "Downloading SQL Server 2016 SSMS..."
    $URL = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/1/D/31D734E0-BFE8-4C33-A9DE-2392808ADEE6/SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe"
    $clnt = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $clnt.DownloadFile($url,$filepath)
    Write-Host "SSMS installer download complete" -ForegroundColor Green
     
    }
    else {
     
    write-host "Located the SQL SSMS Installer binaries, moving on to install..."
    }
     
    # start the SSMS installer
    write-host "Beginning SSMS 2016 install..." -nonewline
    $Parms = " /Install /Quiet /Norestart /Logs log.txt"
    $Prms = $Parms.Split(" ")
    & "$filepath" $Prms | Out-Null
    Write-Host "SSMS installation complete" -ForegroundColor Green
```

PowerShell Script for Downlod ODBC Driver.

```
$url = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/7/1E7B1181-3974-4B29-9A47-CC857B271AA2/English/X64/msodbcsql.msi"
$outpath = "c:/odbc.msi"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outpath

Start-Process -Filepath $outpath -ArgumentList "/qr IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES"
```

Use this command to run command above on your Azure VMs :

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name <VM name> -ResourceGroupName <resource group name>

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -VM $vm  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath "<install odbc or SSMS file path>"
```

Reference : [Azure VM: Update Microsoft ODBC Driver via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000528/azure-vm-update-microsoft-odbc-driver-via-powershell)
https://gist.github.com/justinsoliz/34324700ea93c7b77b4ac3e132584de7

Comment: Thank you for this, I thought I had already replied